# How to make property optional in Maven with Surefire plugin

Tags: java, maven, testng

I am using Surefire plugin to run TestNG suite, I have a requirement to run complete suite or particular tests from `suite.xml`. For the same I have used `testnames` property to provide test name, it works fine with `testnames`
but when I am running with out `testnames` parameter then its throwing exception `The test(s) <[]> cannot be found.`

I want to know is there anything to make it optional?

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>          
          <properties>
            <property>
              <name>testnames</name>
              <value>${testnames}</value>
              
            </property>
          </properties>
          <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
          <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore> 
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
```

Maven command I am using:

```
mvn test -DcfgFile=abc.cfg  -DsuiteXmlFile=Suite.xml -Dtestnames=test1  -f pom.xml -U
```

I want this to work also:

```
mvn test -DcfgFile=abc.cfg  -DsuiteXmlFile=Suite.xml -f pom.xml -U
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make properties optional. But you could create a `DummyTestThatDoesNothing` and define it as default in your POM:

```xml
  <properties>
    <testnames>DummyTestThatDoesNothing</testnames>
  </properties>
```